# How to inject javascript on tomcat server without changing jsp/html file

Tags: javascript, tomcat

is there a way to inject javascript into pages served by tomcat?

I know it can be performed by http://httpd.apache.org/ but not sure about tomcat.

Reason: I do not wish to edit the deployment by project team to perform instrumentation, they might blame me for code change, but if I can inject without change to their code It will insulate myself from being blamed =x

Please provide reason when voting my question so I can improve.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about persistent code, I think the fastest way to inject code is to open up the developer tools and copy&paste the javascript code you need to inject.

In chrome you can edit the source code and when you "save" the changes it will recompile all the javascript code.
Other browsers should have this "feature" as well.

Keep in mind that if you leave/close/refresh the page all the code you have injected will be lost.

Hope this helps

Comment: I do care about persistence code.. that is why I am asking if tomcat can auto inject.